# "view page source" on chrome and get the page data in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome

There are cases that when I right click on a page and choose "view page source" what it shows does not contain the original page data.
For example let's look at this page:

http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Biographies/zgbs/books/2/ref=zg_bs_nav_b_1_b#1

If in chrome we right click and look at the page source it contains for example "The Wright Brothers".

However, if I go to the next page as:

http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Biographies/zgbs/books/2/ref=zg_bs_nav_b_1_b#2

And do the same thing, I expect to see for example: "Unbroken: A World War II" there but it is not there.

What is happening here and how the content of this second page is rendered then?

thanks for your help.